# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract &#39;

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created WCF webservice, while i refer this with some other web service it showing error like "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract '"..

My webconfig is

```
<service name="EenaduMobileFeedTamil.EenaduTamilComments" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

   <endpoint address=""  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EenaduMobileFeedTamil.IEenaduTamilComments" behaviorConfiguration="web">

  </endpoint>
  </service>


 <behaviors>
 <endpointBehaviors>
 <behavior name="web">
 <webHttp />
 </behavior>
 </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  </behavior>
  <behavior name="">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
   </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: did you try updating reference?

Comment: can you show the config file of the client who is consuming this service?

Comment: In client side webconfig there is no tags like <service>.  But i have called this service by      ServiceReference1.EenaduTamilCommentsClient ss = new ServiceReference1.EenaduTamilCommentsClient();
        
     
        ss.InsertComments("1", "ad", "3940B770-B3BA-418D-95ED-2FDA47E357AC", "vignesh", "raj@raj.com", "suer");